# accessing dictionaries in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Basically I want to make a help command for my discord bot in python that uses a dictionary. I'm not done with it yet, and the code for now looks something like this:

```
helpdict = {
  'command1': ['description', 'usage', 'aliases'],
  'command1': ['description', 'usage', 'aliases'],
  #and so on...
}

@commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx, cmd=None):

  if cmd == None:
    await ctx.send(helpdict.keys())
```

The problem is I get an error saying that helpdict is undefined, no matter how i use it. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (btw the code is written in a cog with proper initializing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `helpdict` an attribute of your bot as you are in a Class/Cog

```py
# init
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.bot.helpdict = {
             'command1': ['description', 'usage', 'aliases'],
             'command1': ['description', 'usage', 'aliases'],
             #and so on...
    }

# command
@commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx, cmd=None):

  if cmd == None:
    await ctx.send(self.bot.helpdict.keys())
```

Comment: i fixed it and the code works. Is this something i need to do for all dictionaries? The other variables seem to work fine

Comment: It’s a basic OOP concept @trs-k3tchup, if you want to learn more check [this article](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try removing the default help command.

```
bot.remove_command('help')
```

Put this at the top of your code, after your imports. Then create your own.

Comment: i have already done that in the main.py file

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to not use global variables, these variables are pretty dangerous and it is best to avoid them.
The way to use them in Python is to declare them as `global`. But `discord.py` has a better way of handling global variables, you can introduce them in the `bot` class like this:

```
bot.helpdict = {
  'command1': ['description', 'usage', 'aliases'],
  'command1': ['description', 'usage', 'aliases'],
}

@commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx, cmd=None):

  if cmd == None:
    await ctx.send(self.bot.helpdict.keys())
```